# Calculating time with currency

Tags: time, swift2, nsdate, xcode7.3

Im trying to multiply “hours”  with “pay” rate to give “total pay” in currency i.e. sterling. My code is

```
@IBAction func totalpay (sender : AnyObject) {

let num1 = Double(pay.text!) ?? 00

let num2 = Double(hours.text!) ?? 00

let description = num1 * num2
        totalpayLabel.text! = String(format: "%.2f", (description))

}
```

All “hours” are `NSDate` and “pay” is String

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Where am I going wrong? totalpaylabel does not show result of of time multiplied by rate of pay. The result is always 0.00.

Answer (score 0):

You  are getting 0.0 because one of the values  pay.text or hours.text is not getting converted to numbers , I guess maybe you are not able to get the hours from NSDate correctly as a number  . If you want to  get current hour you can straight away get it with this code .      `let hour =` `NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Hour, fromDate: NSDate())`
.First try to print the values of hours.text and pay.text and you will know what I'm saying

Comment: Im new to coding so where do I put let hour = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Hour, fromDate: NSDate())

Comment: First you need to know is this the code of line that you require , if you do than you can put that line in viewDidLoad() and you have to create an NSDate() to be put to an argument to fromDate: in  this function. your requirement to me is quite unclear , are you taking the hours and pay rate both input from your user , if yes than why are you taking hours in NSDate(), if no than putting the hours as i mentioned will help you.

Comment: You said your hour is NSDate() so just use your hour variable as argument like ( let calhour = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Hour, fromDate : hour) and you need to do this inside your totalpay function once you have value in hour variable , Can you show me how you are getting the value to hour variable in NSDate().